# How to make image retrieval for post request faster using flask?

Tags: python, json, image, api, flask

I am running a Flask app which retrieves image posted by a client. The time it takes to retrieve the image depends on the image size, which is understandable. However, it takes almost 4 seconds to retrieve a 74 kb image and 60 seconds to retrieve a 1.1 MB, which is ridiculously makes my code slower.

I am attaching Server-side code, where the post is done in json format:

```
from flask import Flask, url_for
from flask import request
from flask import json
import time

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/api', methods = ['POST'])
def api_message():

    print(request.headers["Content-Type"])
    if request.headers["Content-Type"] == "application/json":

        start_time = time.time()
        image = request.json['requests'][0]['image']['content']
        elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
        print("Elasped time for serial is: ", elapsed_time, " seconds")

        # image_type = str(type(image))
        data_json = {
            'exec_id': '000',
            'image_type':  'list'
            }

        return json.dumps(data_json)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',debug=False)
```

Client-side request:

```
import requests
import json
import sys, time
import cv2

def main():
    image_file = '0119_right.png'
    image = cv2.imread(image_file)
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    image_list = image.tolist()

    url = 'http://18.90.213.40:5000/api' # the original url is not provided; but can be provided if asked.
    body = {
        'requests': [{
            'image': {
                'type':'py_list',
                'content': image_list
            },
            'hrtf': {
                'type':'sofa',
                'resolution': 1024
            },
            'ping': 'True'
        }]
    }

    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(body), headers=headers)
    print('---------------------------------------------------------------')
    print("Response: ", r.status_code)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    main()
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print("Elasped time for serial is: ", elapsed_time, " seconds")
```

Attached is the image used:[Image for testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFmpG.jpg)

The bottleneck I found is in `image = request.json['requests'][0]['image']['content']`, where it takes around ~4.5 seconds to read a 262K image. 
I am running my server on AWS machine. It's all the same with/without nginx+uswgi setup. I have tried apache. The performance speed is still the same.

Does anyone know if there is any better way to retrieve image in Flask app or how the bottleneck be solved?

Comment: Ever find a faster method/solution?

Comment: @ChrisRockGM  Using base64.